# Добавление кнопки в раздел редактирования поста wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Можно ли добавить кнопку в редакторе определенного типа поста. Хочется добавить кнопку при нажатии на которую происходило событие, ну пусть отправка письма с контентом этого поста. Имеет ли wordpress такой функционал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, такой функционал есть. Добавить свой элемент на страницу редактирования поста можно с помощью функции [add_meta_box()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_meta_box).

Comment: Благодарю, буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

Запутался совсем. Как добавить кнопку разобрался. Каким образом теперь повесить событие, которое будет происходить при клике по этой кнопке. Посмотрел кучу всего. Понял что нужно добавить кастомное событие `do_action`, но как пометить его что оно будет работать при клике на эту кнопку не понятно.